# python range method equivalent in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to initialize an integer array in Swift with numbers 1 to 10. In python, this would be

```
array = range(1, 11)
```

In swift, I came up with the following

```
var array = [Int]()
array = (1..<11).sort()
```

Though this works, I don't like the sort() kind of method to generate this. Is there any other efficient way to generate a list of numbers in swift like range in python.

Comment: Somehow I never hit the other question googling for mins (against which this is marked duplicate). The title of mine is apt when someone is coming from the python world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

either

```
let array = (1...11).map { $0 }
```

or

```
var z = [Int](1...11)
```